# Import module present in a virtualenv in python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to install some modules in virtualenv. And I want to include these modules outside of virtualenv in a python program. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean *"outside of virtualenv"*? The whole point of using a `virtualenv` is to isolate the environment, so that you can only install what your current project needs. If you want to use the same modules in a different project, install them in *that* virtual environment. If you're talking about *distributing* your project, write a `setup.py` and/or `requirements.txt` (the latter is as easy as `pip freeze >> requirements.txt`; you can then `pip install -r requirements.txt` for the new project to get all dependencies, if that's what you're after).

Comment: In a global environment I have one module with version x and that version will be used by main program. I want to add a plugin to that main program. But my plugin  requires module version y.

Comment: So I want to keep module with version y in a virtualenv and write a wrapper for my plugin to import module from virtualenv.

Comment: You can't run the plug-in in a different virtual environment to the main program! You should spend your time figuring out how to get them both using the same version.